# How far should I go back in Russian History in order to understand Communist Russia?

Tags: soviet-union, russia, communism, stalin, lenin

I'm writing a story and need information on the Russian communist rule because I'm writing a book about a government much like that of communist Russia, specifically focused on a police state  government like USSR. My question is in order to understand USSR police state and the steps to get their, like Naomi Wolf's book "The E,nd of America", where should I start to understand communism time wise? Someone said 1850 right before the Russian revolution. Is early Russian and Slavic heritage history needed to understand communist rule under Stalin and Lenin?

Comment: Why don't you read e.g. [Orlando Figes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orlando_Figes)' *A People's Tragedy: The Russian Revolution: 1891-1924* cover-to-cover? I must hasten to add that Figes is no Naomi Wolf, though :)

Comment: Not sure you are being well-served when you are relying on Naomi Wolf for figuring out America...

Comment: Your question is quite localized; as stated, it can have no value to anyone other than you. Stack Exchange works best when the Q&A creates answers that can serve many people.  Could you rephrase the question to be less about you and more about history?

Comment: I am afraid you may be laboring under the illusion that there is a small discrete set of books that is sufficient to understand X (X may be a country, an ideology, whatever). Unfortunately, there is no such set.

Comment: Beware of lots of propaganda on both sides. For instance, I'd argue about the USSR being consistently a "police state".

Comment: @astabada - that depends on your definition of "police state".

Comment: @DVK to start with, there was no "police" in the USSR, the police was abolished after 1918 and even the very word "police" became prejorative (there were numerous protests when the pro-western president Medvedev re-invented the word in 2011). This is because the Tsarist police was known for its brutality and because the word associated with the Nazi collaborationists. In Ukraine and Belarus there is still no "police".

Comment: @Anixx - That's just word games. "Police" in "police state" means law enforcement ("siloviki" if you wish), not an organization with the exact name "Police". I'm pretty sure that most countries outside Nazi Germany that are/were considered police states named their police with a different word.

Comment: @DVK the numbers of the law enforcement (i.e. the police) today is far greater than during the whole Soviet period. The number of the law enforcement personnel per a unit of population in 2011 is twice greater than in 1953 (at the death of Stalin). They are also more heavily armed, that is they patrol the streets with submachineguns, which was impossible in the USSR (in the Brezhnev's times they usually even had no combat charges in their pistols).

Comment: @DVK *ça va sans dire,* otherwise we could argue that it depends on your defintion of "depends" and so on (forever) :)

Answer (score 5):

No, it is not needed. I think you better should read the history of Marxism and about the Great French Revolution. If you want to deepen in history, you can start from the [Commune of Rome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commune_of_Rome) (1144).

Answer (score 5):

For me at least, this question may be re-phrased thus: To what extent were the contours of the Communist regime in Russia determined by Russian national peculiarities?

Scholars like [Richard Pipes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Pipes) hold that the Soviet regime was a development of some sort of immanent Russian matrix. Here is a wiki summary:

> Pipes is known for arguing that the origins of the Soviet Union can be
>   traced to the separate path taken by 15th century Muscovy, in a
>   Russian version of the [Sonderweg thesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonderweg). In Pipes' opinion, Muscovy
>   differed from every state in Europe in that it had no concept of
>   private property, and that everything was regarded as the property of
>   the Grand Duke/Tsar. In Pipes' view, this separate path undertaken by
>   Russia (possibly under Mongol influence) ensured that Russia would be
>   an autocratic state with values fundamentally dissimilar from those of
>   Western civilization. Pipes has argued that this "patrimonialism" of
>   Imperial Russia started to break down when Russian leaders attempted
>   to modernize in the 19th century, without seeking to change the basic
>   "patrimonial" structure of Russian society.

There are also more nuanced versions of this argument. However, it is far from universally accepted and I personally am not quite convinced by it for this reason: other Communist regimes like in China or Cambodia have acted similarly, without the "immanent Russian matrix" so there must be more (or less!) to it. In fact, just by reading 1984 you can learn most of what you need about how any police state works (of course, 1984 is what in science one would call an "ideal case" - a model that real states only approximate to some degree, and thank God for that!).

Comment: [Popper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Open_Society_and_Its_Enemies) would argue it all started with [Plato](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plato) ... :)

Comment: @Drux: LOL. I actually only read the second volume, where he indicts Hegel. :)

Comment: Yep, I also read that Popper actually respected Plato and Marx (just not the respective -isms), but not Hegel :)

Comment: @Drux: It makes sense for me. He more or less turned me off Hegel forever.

Comment: Possibly you could also take a look at this question: http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/2354/what-are-the-origins-of-the-totalitarian-genes-theory Regarding the book of "1984" I do not recommend making any conclusions on this book: it depicts a very *untypical* "police state". I cannot imagine anything close to it is reality (especially the quick-changing the propaganda and universally-accepted double-think). I think, it is a very artificial fictitious construction.

Comment: " Soviet regime was a development of some sort of immanent Russian matrix." - I'd argue that this view started with Marx himself :)

Comment: @DVK: How? As far as I know, Marx expected the revolution to happen in Germany, not in Russia.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg - Exactly.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [strain of historical thought](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongol_invasion_of_Rus%27#Influence_on_Rus.27_society) that some of the features of Russian/Soviet state are strongly influenced by Mongol conquest and rule by the Horde.

So if you agree with that line of thought, you need to go [back to 13th century](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongol_invasion_of_Rus%27).

Comment: Hmmm (thinking) ... Lenin returned from Switzerland, so maybe the Swiss, of all people, are to blame ... (oh well :)

Comment: @Drux - IIRC, it was a popular conspiracy in Russia/USSR that Lenin's return was facilitated by Germans to help them in the war.

Comment: Hmmm ... but they thought it to us as fact in school ... just confirmed that Orlando Figes (reference above) also reports it (i.e. the German, not the Swiss, connection :) as fact (p. 385) ... could still be wrong, although chances are perhaps slim now

Comment: @Drux can you please clarify what they thought in the school - something about Lenin or the idea that Russians have totalitarian(or slave) mentality due to Mongol blood/rule?

Comment: @Anixx to quote Figes: "The Russian exiles made contact with the German authorities, who quickly saw the advantage of letting the Bolsheviks … go back to Russia to stir up discord there … They even helped to finance [Bolshevik] activities … The train [which brought Lenin back to Russia] was 'sealed' in the sense that no inspections of passports or luggage were carried out by the Germans on the way." Clear enough?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that Russian Communism can be explained by the autocracy of the later Czars, Peter the Great, or even Ivan the Terrible. That is, with regard to the idea of centralized authority and the "command and control" methods of these rulers.

The Okrana, or Russian secret police goes back to the Tsarist rulers of the 19th century. Ivan the Terrible created the streltsy, or "Guards" arm, that doubled as police.